# ElasticSearch 5.2 Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [script]. request

Tags: elasticsearch

Hello I am trying to remove record by searching in nested data of array via script.
Is possible to remove data with using script for _delete_by_query ?
Version of elasticsearch 5.2

My request looks like

```
POST /test_index/_delete_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field":"userPermission"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "script":{
    "inline":"""
    for (int i = 0; i < ctx._source.userPermission.size(); i++) {
        if(ctx._source.userPermission[i].id == '760100000-100000')
        {
          return true
        }
    }
    return false
    """
  }
}
```

I get an error:

{
"error": {
"type": "parsing_exception",
"reason": "Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [script].",
"line": 1,
"col": 77
},
"status": 400
}

It is example of data:

```
{
    "_index": "test_index",
    "_type": "doc",
    "_id": "AXXDZFKKgDFBfUY9kVS6",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "test_field": "Test",
      "userPermission": [
        {
          "fullName": "Test 55",
          "id": '760100000-100000'
        },
        {
          "fullName": "Test33",
          "id": 555
        },
        {
          "fullName": "Test 1",
          "id": 444
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [delete by query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html) endpoint doesn't support any script content. What you need to do is to use the [update by query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html#docs-update-by-query-api-source) endpoint and the `delete` operation if the condition is satisfied:

```
POST /test_index/_update_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field":"userPermission"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "script":{
    "inline":"""
      for (int i = 0; i < ctx._source.userPermission.size(); i++) {
        if(ctx._source.userPermission[i].id == '760100000-100000')
        {
          ctx.op = 'delete';
        }
      }
    """
  }
}
```